# springSecurityFilterChain bean not found using MockMVC and @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm testing a spring rest controller using spring MockMVC.
I am able to execute mock http requests and verify the response.
My setup autowires the WebApplicationContext:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTestClass {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webAppContext)
            .apply(springSecurity()).build();
}
```

To tell MockMVC what controllers to initialize and add to the context I have an internal config class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages = {"com.acme"},
        useDefaultFilters = false,
        includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value={MyRestController.class, MyRestControllerDependency.class})
        })
@EnableWebMvc
static class MyTestClassConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MyClassRepository myClassRepository() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyClassRepository.class);
    }
```

And this works like a charm. MockMVC spins up a container with a context that loaded MyRestController and serves the urls mapped by MyRestController.
Now, some of MyRestControllers methods are annotated with: `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMINISTRATOR')")` so the next step is to test that.

Reading the Integration part of the Spring security testing guide
[spring security and test-mockmvc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html#test-mockmvc-setup)
 it seems all I should do is call the org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.springSecurity() in the MockMvcBuilders `.apply()` function calls.

This does not work, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.
```

I tried adding a bean definition to my internal config class like so:

```
    Filter springSecurityFilterChain() {
        return new FilterChainProxy();
    }
```

While this does provide a springSecurityFilterChain, the instance is empty and when I run the test I get a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:224)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Which, is understandable, by instantiating the FilterChainProxy directly, it is indeed empty.

I suspect I need to configure my component scan to include springs' instances of the FilterChainProxy. *If* that is the issue, I don't know what classes I should include. I have tried including all the classes:

```
        includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value={TenantAPI.class, TenantManager.class}),
                          @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="^org\\.springframework\\.security.*")})
```

But this gives the same error: "Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurity.." as when I run the test without the additional Regex filter.

Does anyone know how I can get the springSecurityFilterChain when I am being picky with the internal classes I let MockMVC instantiate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you must have a `@Configuration` class somewhere that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`? This is the configuration you need to set up Spring security.

You need to include this class in your component scan in your test configuration.

Comment: Yes there is. I actually did that yesterday but shied away because it autowires up a bunch of stuff. Spring complained it can't create beans with name "_somename_" no qualifying... I will give that a better go today, thank you!