# Spring MockMVC FilterChainProxy.getFilters() Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, filter, chain, mockmvc

I am trying to test our OAuth's resource server endpoints using MockMVC, but I am having trouble configuring the Security Filter Chain Proxy.

Below is the code for my Test Class, in which unit tests that call the endpoints listed in my ItemController are defined:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes ={FilterChainProxy.class})
public class ItemCTest {

@InjectMocks
private ItemController itemController;


@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;


private MockMvc  mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    System.out.println(springSecurityFilterChain);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(itemController).apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain)).build();
}
```

I also have the following classes in my config directory, which may or may not be relevant to the actual problem. :

WebSecurityAppInitializer

```
public class WebSecurityAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

}
}
```

When I try to run a sample test defined in my test class, this is log message that gets spits out:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.getFilters(FilterChainProxy.java:224)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:197)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:127)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
at com.vertexinc.ventures.resourceserver.controller.ItemCTest.test(ItemCTest.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
```

Note that everything works perfectly when I launch the server and ping the endpoints via Postman, so I know that there isn't a problem with the configuration. I'm just not sure why that configuration is not being applied to the Test class, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is related to [springSecurityFilterChain bean not found using MockMVC and @ComponentScan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46936469/springsecurityfilterchain-bean-not-found-using-mockmvc-and-componentscan).

I had this problem and then I added my security configuration to the @ContextConfiguration.

So, your code above would have this annotation.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    FilterChainProxy.class,
    WebSecurityConfig.class
})
```